# Stacking divs side by side to the right of a container (with another div anchored left)

Tags: html, css

This is what I want to achieve (montaged pic):

[image: rightfloat-2.png]

The red outline is the container, with size calculated relative to the page/browser window. Then, I'd want two divs (green dashed), with width 15% of the container (and height 100% of it), to stick to the right of the container, taking as much space as they need - and finally, I'd like a left aligned div (blue dashed) with height 100% of container, to take up the rest of the remaining width.

Unfortunately, the closest I got to is this:

```htm
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>test-rightfloat</title>
    <style type="text/css">
body {
  width: 100%;
}
.cntr {
  width: 60vh; height: 15vh;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
.lb {
  width: 70%; height: 100%;
  border: 2px dashed blue;
  display: inline-block;
}
.gr {
  width: 15%; height: 100%;
  border: 2px dashed green;
  float: right;/**/
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 5em;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
  /*margin-right:0;
  margin-left:auto;*/
  /*position: absolute; right: 0; left: auto;*/
}
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
<div id="contain" class="cntr">
  <div id="leftblue" class="lb"></div>
  <div id="greenright1" class="gr">A</div>
  <div id="greenright1" class="gr">B</div>
</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

... which produces this (Firefox 43):

[image: rightfloat-1.png]

... which is not what I had in mind: the right divs try both to stick to the right edge of the container, and so they do not stand side-by-side, but on top of each-other instead...

Is there anything I could do to get the desired design (preferably in pre-CSS5, and without changing the HTML structure - and no JS)?

Comment: squeeze your dimensions a little bit or change to border box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is due to the **border**. When adding a border you should consider adding twice the border width to your actual position or delete the borders

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>test-rightfloat</title>
    <style type="text/css">
body {
  width: 100%;
}
.cntr {
  width: 60vh; height: 15vh;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
.lb {
  width: 70%; height: 100%;
  /*border: 2px dashed blue;*/   <--- NO BORDER
  display: inline-block;
}
.gr {
  width: 15%; height: 100%;
  /*border: 2px dashed green;*/  <--- NO BORDER
  float: right;/**/
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 5em;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
  /*margin-right:0;
  margin-left:auto;*/
  /*position: absolute; right: 0; left: auto;*/
}
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
<div id="contain" class="cntr">
  <div id="leftblue" class="lb"></div>
  <div id="greenright1" class="gr">A</div>
  <div id="greenright1" class="gr">B</div>
</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Many thanks @hugodecasta - I had no idea it was the borders that made the change in alignment. For testing in browser, I added `background-color:rgba(0,200,0,0.5);` to class `.gr`, and one can clearly see then, the design was as intended. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Flexbox` here, just use `flex: 0 0 15%` on `.gr` and `flex: 1` on `.lb`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.cntr {
  width: 60vh; 
  height: 15vh;
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: flex;
}
.lb { 
  border: 2px dashed blue;
  flex: 1;
}
.gr {
  flex: 0 0 15%;
  border: 2px dashed green;
}
```

```html
<div id="contain" class="cntr">
  <div id="leftblue" class="lb"></div>
  <div id="greenright1" class="gr">A</div>
  <div id="greenright2" class="gr">B</div>
</div>
```

Update: Actually since you have fixed width of `15%` on both `.gr` you can just use `70%` on `.lb` with `floats` but you need to add `box-sizing: border-box`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.cntr {
  width: 60vh; 
  height: 15vh;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
.lb { 
  border: 2px dashed blue;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}
.gr {
  width: 15%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px dashed green;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="contain" class="cntr">
  <div id="leftblue" class="lb">Left</div>
  <div id="greenright1" class="gr">A</div>
  <div id="greenright2" class="gr">B</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Many thanks @NenadVracar - `flex` is a CSS3 property, and I need to work with this in a CSS2 syntax; however your solution does work great in a proper browser. Cheers!

Comment: Can you use `calc` or `tables`?

Comment: Thanks, @NenadVracar - but unfortunately no; the engine I work with supports neither `calc`, not even `display: table-cell;` and the like...

Comment: @sdaau i updated my answer, also i just saw you have same `id`'s and you cant do that.